# How to read a column number by number in java

Tags: java

I'm now reading a text file in `java` .The content in txt file has 267 rows and 23 columns and all the numbers are 0/1.I use Scanner input and

```
input.nextLine.split(" ")
```

to get the columns of the file and store them as

```
string array(String[] cols).
```

For example,if my txt file is

```
 1000001
 0000110
 1111010
 1010101
```

I get 1011 as my first

```
column(cols[0])
```

I wonder how to compute the number of 1 in this column and every other column as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Share your efforts to resolve the problem

Comment: `column(cols[0])` does it return a String or an Array?

Answer (score 0):

If the array is like String cols[]={"1000001","0000110","1111010","1010101"};

Then you can try like this

```
    int colLength=cols[0].length();     
    for(int j=0;j<colLength;j++){
        int totalOnes=0;
        int i=0;
        for(;i<cols.length;i++){
            if(cols[i].charAt(j)=='1')
                totalOnes++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total ones at column "+j+" ="+totalOnes);
    }
```